# jQuery $(this) when return what?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two div elements, these div elements contains one select each.

```
<div id="signup_dialog">
   <select name="cb_country">
      <option value="0"></option>
   </select>
</div>

<div id="create_dialog">
   <select name="cb_country">
      <option value="0"></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

When I change select in each each div elements, `$(this)` returns `$("#signup_dialog")` or `$("#create_dialog")` (the DIVs), but I want to get select element with `$(this)`.

In other words,  `this` is the parent div, and not the select.  How can I get the select inside my event handler?

Js code:

```
$("select[name=cb_country]","#signup_dialog,#create_dialog").live("change",function(){
   console.log("element",$(this));
});
```

Comment: so what's the question?  Did you want the currently selected __value__ ?

Comment: @Alnitak: `this` is the div, he wants it to be the select box.

Comment: @Rocket ah, got you, because of the delegation... hmm.

Comment: Is it about delegation or the fact that we want to provide a context to the selector?
Because if you still use .live(), without providing a context to the selector, this will be the select element. I don't think event delegation is involved here.
I created a jsfiddle here for us to experiment with this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/h2my6/

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` will refer to whichever element invokes the change function. Does the function not work with just the select?

```
$("select[name=cb_country]").live("change",function(){
   console.log("element",$(this));
});
```

`$(this).val()` will give the value of selected option.

Comment: this work but I have 3 select element for now and I want add "change" listener only to two select elements and I did not give id attributes to each elements because maybe I will create a new country select and add same listener to it without give any id or class.

Comment: You have to have some way to identify them. Perhaps mark this as answered and ask a new question.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. I will ask this as new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the currently selected *value*, use this:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].val;
```

or if you really must use expensive jQuery functions, use:

```
$(this).val();
```

Comment: Inside his event handler, `this` is referring to the div, not the select.  That's the issue here.

Comment: Is `val()` considered more expensive than `.val`?

Comment: @Jivings yes, absolutely.  There's an overhead in wrapping the element in a jQuery object, and then more overhead in the `.val()` function because it has to figure out what sort of object(s) it has been called on.

Comment: @Jivings no, AFAIK you need the `.val` of the selected `<option>` child (per my answer) and not of the `<select>` node itself.

Comment: Ah sorry, for some reason I thought we were commenting on my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the selected value of `<select>` with jQuery, you can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$('select').val();
```

In you event handler, `this` is your select so you can do:

```
$(this).val();
// or
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/zLDZH/)**

---

**Edit: It seems I've missed the event delegation part.**

First [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been **deprecated**, which means the method could be removed in any future version of the library, you should not use it anymore if you are using a version of jquery above 1.6.

You should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegation/). Besides both these new methods will set a correct `this` pointing to the `select` element.

In any case, using `e.target` will ensure that you point to the element that triggered the event, in our case the select.

Here are some implementations using the different methods:

```
$("select[name=cb_country]","#signup_dialog,#create_dialog").live('change', function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).val());
});

$("#signup_dialog,#create_dialog").on('change', 'select[name=cb_country]', function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).val());
});

$("#signup_dialog,#create_dialog").delegate('select[name=cb_country]', 'change', function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).val());
});
```

Comment: Inside his event handler, `this` is referring to the div, not the select. That's the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this`, use `event.target`.

```
$("select[name='cb_country']", "#signup_dialog,#create_dialog").live("change",function(event){
   console.log("element",$(event.target));
});
```

`this` doesn't seem to be working because it seems jQuery doesn't like multiple elements as a context.  Not sure why.

UPDATE: It seems this is an issue with `live`, as the following works fine:

```
$("select[name='cb_country']", "#signup_dialog,#create_dialog").change(function(){
   console.log("element",$(this));
});
```

If you're using jQuery >= 1.7, replace `.live` with `.on`.

```
$("#signup_dialog,#create_dialog").on("change", "select[name='cb_country']", function(){
       console.log("element",$(this));
});
```

If you're using jQuery >= 1.4.3  and jQuery <= 1.7, then use `.delegate` (I suggest updating to 1.7.1, and using `.on`):

```
$("#signup_dialog,#create_dialog").delegate("select[name='cb_country']", "change", function(){
       console.log("element",$(this));
});
```

NOTE: If the elements are being added via AJAX, you should use `.on` like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#signup_dialog select[name='cb_country'],#create_dialog select[name='cb_country']", function(){
    console.log("element",$(this));
});
```

Comment: I am using live because I am getting div and scripts with ajax.I am using jQuery 1.7 but I cant run above codes.Only work event.target method.I wonder there is any drawback to use this.event method ? If not I can use it :)

Comment: @mesuutt: The only drawback is that `.live` is deprecated, and may be removed in newer jQuery versions.  Other than that, no, it should be fine.  Actually, can you try using this: `$(document).on("change", "#signup_dialog select[name='cb_country'],#create_dialog select[name='cb_country']", function(){console.log("element",$(this));});`.?  With `on`, the element must be something that exists in the DOM (unlike `live`).  This should work for content loaded via AJAX.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you are looking for this :

```
$("select[name=cb_country]",$("#signup_dialog,#create_dialog")).live("change",function(){
   console.log("element",$(this));
});
```

The second parameter to `$()` must be either a DOM element, or Document, or jQuery object, but not a selector.

With this solution, `this` should be your select element.

Comment: The 2nd parameter of `$()` can be a selector.  `$('p', 'body')` works just fine.

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware of that as this is not documented.